# React: location.state is undefined on first time navigating after page load

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, location

I have a React component, which display a Link:

**Magic.tsx:**

```
const { message } = this.props;
<Link to={ { pathname: HOGWARTS, state: { message } } }>
  Go to Page
</Link>
```

I am passing this `Magic` Component as a Prop to another component, where I am iterating over it, with Dynamic `message` state

**Parent.tsx**

```
const CustomComp = this.props.Magic;
const content = messageArray.map(msg => <CustomComp message={ msg } />)
{ content } //Render all the Links with message state
```

This is rendering the Link correctly. But when I click on the Link and debug the `HOGWARTS` page, the location.state is undefined.
If go back to previous page, and click again, the location.state is correct, having `message` data.
So somehow it's not working on page load, but after clicking on second time, it works.

Did anyone faced the same issue?

**Note:** I've inspected the `<Link />` tag using `React Devtool`, on sidebar it shows that, what `message` state is attached to this link.

Answer (score 2):

’state‘ match 'BrowserRouter','hash' match 'HashRouter',so if you use 'HashRouter' match 'hash', 'state' must be undefined

Answer (score 0):

You just need to handle your state: { message }  undefined case like below , as the state will be available only when the Link is clicked

So `location.state` is undefined at initial .

In your  Parent.tsx

You can do something like this ..

```
const message =
            (this.props.location.state && this.props.location.state.message) != undefined
                ? this.props.location.state.message
                : " ";
```

And then use it

```
const content = messageArray.map(msg => <CustomComp message={ msg } />)
```

This should help you .. :)